# Why <span> does not contain the text in BeautifulSoup despite the fact that exactly the same <span> from the website contains it?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape **3 elements** from this website:

http://www.altitude-maps.com/city/170_562,Poznan,Wielkopolskie,Poland

I need **latitude, longitude and elevation**, so my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.altitude-maps.com/city/170_562,Poznan,Wielkopolskie,Poland'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, features="html.parser")

latitude = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'curLat'}).get_text()
longitude = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'curLng'}).get_text()
elevation1 = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'altitude'}).get_text()  # from the text in the center
elevation2 = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'curElevation'}).get_text()  # from the box in the left
```

It finds values for the latitude and the longitude, but it doesn't for the elevation (in both cases). **Instead of getting '80.33 m' and '80.33 m (263.55 ft)' I get white space and empty str.**

Comparision of HTML from the BS and from the website:

```
BS_elevation1 = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'altitude'}) 
#  BS_elevation1: <span id="altitude" style="font-size: 1.5em;"> </span>
#  This part on the website: <span id="altitude" style="font-size: 1.5em;">80.33 m (263.55 ft)</span>

BS_elevation2 = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'curElevation'})
#  BS_elevation2: <span id="curElevation" style=""></span>
#  This part on the website: <span id="curElevation" style>80.33 m</span>
```

It seems like the text is available on the website, but it's not available in BeautifulSoup. I can't understand why it happens. How to get over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you're searching for is embedded within the page inside `<script>` tag, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can however use `re` module to parse the page.

To get latitude, longitude and elevation you can use this example:

```py
import re
import requests

url = "http://www.altitude-maps.com/city/170_562,Poznan,Wielkopolskie,Poland"
text = requests.get(url).text

lat = re.search(r"geoplugin_latitude.*?([\d.-]+)", text).group(1)
lon = re.search(r"geoplugin_longitude.*?([\d.-]+)", text).group(1)
elv = re.search(r"geoip_elevation.*?([\d.-]+)", text).group(1)

print("Latitude:", lat)
print("Longitude:", lon)
print("Elevation:", elv)
```

Prints:

```
Latitude: 52.4063740
Longitude: 16.9251681
Elevation: 80.329216003418
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import httpx
import trio
import re


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        r = await client.get('http://www.altitude-maps.com/city/170_562,Poznan,Wielkopolskie,Poland')
        goal = re.findall(r"(lati|long|elev).*?'(.+)'", r.text)
        print(goal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
[('lati', '52.4063740'), ('long', '16.9251681'), ('elev', '80.329216003418')]
```

Comment: @QHarr which Python/Trio version you are using  ?

Comment: @QHarr Sounds strange. what's the name of the script itself ? also what happens when you run your script via `python script.py` ? make sure there's no file with the name `trio` within same directory  folder !

Comment: @QHarr :) it happens some times

Comment: @QHarr :D actually am one of it's contributor, Sure let me know if you've any question regarding it or any. am an async lover :)

Comment: @QHarr sorry just got the notification. shall i apply the example on real website you've ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the elevation is not filled in when the page is presented.  Do a "view source" in your browser and you'll see that; it's filled in by Javascript.

Do note, however, that the data you want is all present in the Javascript code in the second Javascript block.  That should be pretty easy to parse.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what happened there. I understand why I managed to scrape the latitude and the longitude, but my question is: why is the latitude and longitude in the website's source, but the elevation isn't? I assume that every  element depends on the Javascript code in the second Javascript block, so what's the difference between latitude/longitude and the elevation? Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Similar regex idea but  using a dictionary comprehension

```
import re, requests

items = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'elevation']
r = requests.get('http://www.altitude-maps.com/city/170_562,Poznan,Wielkopolskie,Poland').text

data = {item: re.search(r"(?<={}).*'(.*?)'".format(item), r).group(1) for item in items}
print(data)
```